# Group By and replace column values in spark Dataset

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have the below datasets in spark where I need to perform a join condition .

```
+---+------+-------+--------+------------------------+----+--------+
|ID |PState|MState |dt      |TS                      |proc|daterank|
+---+------+-------+--------+------------------------+----+--------+
|1  |Iowa  |Kansas |20240212|null                    |2   |1       |
|1  |Iowa  |CA     |20250212|null                    |4   |2       |
|2  |Maine |Chicago|20240212|2024-01-01T00:00:00.000Z|2   |1       |
|2  |NJ    |NY     |20250212|null                    |4   |2       |
|3  |CA    |MS     |20240212|null                    |2   |1       |
|3  |NJ    |NY     |20240212|null                    |4   |1       |
|3  |NJ    |WV     |20240212|null                    |9   |1       |
+---+------+-------+--------+------------------------+----+--------+

+---+------+------+--------+----+-----+---------+
|bID|PState|MState|bdt     |bTS |bproc|bdaterank|
+---+------+------+--------+----+-----+---------+
|1  |Iowa  |CA    |20250212|null|4    |2        |
|2  |NJ    |NY    |20250212|null|4    |2        |
|3  |CA    |MS    |20240212|null|2    |1        |
|3  |NJ    |NY    |20240212|null|4    |1        |
|3  |NJ    |WV    |20240212|null|9    |1        |
+---+------+------+--------+----+-----+---------+
```

I need to join the datasets such that the output will be

```
+---+------+-------+--------+------------------------+----+--------+
|ID |PState|MState |dt      |TS                      |proc|daterank|
+---+------+-------+--------+------------------------+----+--------+
|1  |Iowa  |CA     |20240212|null                    |2   |1       |
|1  |Iowa  |CA     |20250212|null                    |4   |2       |
|2  |Maine |Chicago|20240212|2024-01-01T00:00:00.000Z|2   |1       |
|2  |Maine |Chicago|20250212|null                    |4   |2       |
|3  |CA    |MS     |20240212|null                    |2   |1       |
|3  |NJ    |NY     |20240212|null                    |4   |1       |
|3  |NJ    |WV     |20240212|null                    |9   |1       |
+---+------+-------+--------+------------------------+----+--------
```

I have tried the below code but it's not working

```
filteredDfDate.withColumn("maxPoints", max("maxPoints").over(Window.partitionBy("bdaterank","bID","maxPoints")))
              .withColumn("enrichedFinalPState",when(col("bdaterank").notEqual(col("maxPoints")).and(col("enrichedPState").isNull()),max(col("enrichedPState"))).otherwise(lit("null")))
              //.where(col("daterank").equalTo(col("maxPoints"))).withColumnRenamed("PState","enrichedPState")
              .withColumn("enrichedFinalMState",when(col("bdaterank").notEqual(col("maxPoints")).and(col("enrichedMState").isNull()),max(col("enrichedMState"))).otherwise(lit("null")))
             .show(false);
```

Can someone please help me